# cmd+click in safari not always opening website in a new tab

Tags: safari

I'm experiencing this issue that some links on websites I can right click and click open in new tab and it works correctly but cmd+click does not. I was under the impression that this is the exact same action? It is incredibly annoying having this feature work 50% of the time. Is there a way to override this behaviour somehow?

Comment: cmnd=click works also ctrl+click brings up the right-click menu.

Comment: @SolarMike that's my point. Cmd+click not always works. There are some websites that override this behaviour.